# Can I superglue keycap to laptop keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, asus-rog-zephyrus

I have Asus zephyrus g14 laptop. By mistake, I spilled cola on my laptop so I took the keycaps off and cleaned them with alcohol and put them back in but some keycaps broke(the small things below keycaps broke), and now it cant fit back in the keyboard. So can I superglue the keycap to the keyboard? I have looked for keycaps but it isn't available, and the whole keyboard replacement is expensive for me.

Comment: You can get a new keyboard for between $£€ 10 & 25 on eBay, for just about anything. I wouldn't even bother trying to fix the old one.

Answer (score 4):

No. The parts underneath the keycap are a mechanism that moves when you press a key. In particular, the parts that clip into the keycap will rotate or slide a small amount when the key is pressed - if you glue the two together, you'll have a solid key that doesn't move.

You'll need replacement parts, either a whole working keyboard, a broken keyboard to salvage the parts from, or individual spare parts.

Answer (score 1):

Well short answer **no**.

The Long answer , *Yes but ,try at your own risk*.
The key might malfunction if not done properly.

There are many tutorials and articles that demonstrate how to do this but I have curated this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001245.htm) that might help you get it back and running perfectly.

Do let me know if it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).